# Space key deletes in eclipse

Tags: java

Pressing space key in eclipse **deletes** the characters. Even in Microsoft Word or **Wordpad**.

I think I screwed some preferences in eclipse of my keyboard settings

Please Help.

Comment: Is it happening when you press the `spacebar` key or any key

Comment: this has nothing to do with java or eclipse, because its happening in Word and WordPad too

Comment: check your keyboard and regional settings in Control Panel (only for Windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try By pressing the insert or ins. key which would disable the overtype mode of windows.
Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

You may have accidentally pressed the Insert key on your keyboard. Press it again to disable it. Look for a key named Ins on your keyboard, most probably to your right.

Comment: This is helped me ,.. Thank a lot brother !